# Is this snake hazardous around children?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

This snake lives in a small rock dam in a residential retention pond in Chattanooga, TN[image].  Children play in the area at times.  It is approximately 30 inches in length. Is this snake a hazard or can it be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a northern water snake.

[image]

<sup>TN.gov</sup>

Nonvenomous. Not dangerous if left alone, From tn.gov:

> When threatened Northern Watersnakes will make a silent retreat, but are aggressive when captured. They will flatten their head and neck, try to strike and bite, and discharge a foul-smelling musk from glands at the base of their tail.

See https://www.tn.gov/twra/wildlife/reptiles/snakes/northern-watersnake.html

Comment: The fat body is quite reminiscent of a cottonmouth, but it doesn't have the mottling I associate with them.